# ¿Cómo puedo pedir en 1 sólo prompt 4 valores de una función en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a aprender **Javascript** y estoy viendo **funciones**.

Me surgió la siguiente duda. Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function hola(num1, num2, num3, num4) {}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pedir los 4 valores en 1 sólo prompt?

Hasta ahora los estoy pidiendo así:

```
  num1 = prompt("Write the First Number between 0 and 9");
  num2 = prompt("Write the Second Number between 0 and 9");
  num3 = prompt("Write the Third Number between 0 and 9");
  num4 = prompt("Write the Fourth Number between 0 and 9");
```

Pero me gustaría poder pedirlos todos juntos en un sólo **prompt**.

```
document.write("Muchas Gracias")
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías pedirle que ingrese 4 numero separados por, por ejemplo, coma.

Comment: Lo estoy intentando pero tampoco consigo que me tire los cuatro valores. Me sale 

undefinedundefinedundefined1,2,3,4

Comment: Como dijo @Marcos es una opción pedir los 4 valores separados por comas, solo tendrías que realizar un split y convertir los valores a números ya que *Prompt* siempre te devuelve un String

Comment: Las respuestas, van en el campo respuestas. hiciste el recorrido y decia eso, no? si no, porfa, vuelve a mirar el [tour]...

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres recoger todos los valores en una sola entrada puedes pedir al usuario que los escriba separados por coma (u otro caracter) y luego crear un array mediante `split` para obtener cada dato diferenciado.

No obstante, queda por controlar que:

- No se escriba entre comas un valor diferente de una cifra entre  `0` y `9`
- Se escriban exactamente 4 valores separados por coma

No sé exactamente de qué trate tu programa, lo cierto es que la lógica que quieres implementar aquí no es muy acertada, sobre todo por la dificultad de escribir un código controlado.

De todos modos, aquí te dejo esa posiblidad.

```js
mValues = prompt("Write four numbers between 0 and 9 separated by ,");
console.log(mValues);
var allValues = mValues.split(',');
console.log(allValues[0]);
console.log(allValues[1]);
console.log(allValues[2]);
console.log(allValues[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya todos dicen lo puedes hacer pidiendo todos los datos y luego separarlos pero ¿y si quieres más datos?

```
let nums = "1,2,3,4" //esto es el resultado del prompt 
//aqui separamos los valores 
//esto retorna un array con todos los valores
nums = nums.split(",")

//obtenemos cada uno de los valores 
num1= parseInt(nums[0])
num2 = parseInt(nums[1])
num3 = parseInt(nums[2])
num4 = parseInt(nums[3])

console.log(num1,num2,num3,num4)
```

Pero que pasa si deseas más valores o si el usuario pone todos los números del 0 al 9, para eso lo podrías hacer con un forEach

```
//hacemos lo mismo 
let nums = "1,2,3,4" //esto es el resultado del prompt 
//aqui separamos los valores 
//esto retorna un array con todos los valores 
nums = nums.split(",")

//en tu función hola ahora solo tenemos un argumento que será el array de todos los números ingresados 

function hola(nums){
    nums.forEach(num => console.log(num))
}
hola(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como cada `prompt` requiere que el usuario ingrese un valor, no puedes nada mas ponerlos todos juntos, necesitas que se ejecute 4 veces. Lo que puedes hacer es un bucle, o algo similar, para leer los valores, y así eliminar algo de código duplicado. Puedes usar la función `forEach` de JavaScript:

```
function hola(num1, num2, num3, num4) {}

var myArr = [0, 0, 0, 0];

myArr.map((x,i, arr) => (arr[i] = prompt("Write a Number between 0 and 9")));

hola(...myArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré esta solución no se si será la mejor pero me está sirviendo para el jueguito que estoy armando.

```
function hola(num1, num2, num3, num4) {
  
  [num1,num2,num3,num4] = prompt("Write a 4-Digit Number.");

}
```